# BuildInfo.config file doesnt have correct buildLabel and ProjectVersionSpect, it has autogenerated labels

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, msbuild-task, azure-pipelines

i have converted my build definition from xml based to TFS2015 vNext based. I am using following command to build my solution.

```
/property:OutDir="$(BUILD.BINARIESDIRECTORY)"\x64\ /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=True /p:IncludeServerNameInBuildInfo=True
```

After using **p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile** option it generates the buildinfo.config file but the build label in it is not correct, it has some autogenerated no. as follows

```
  <MSBuild>
  <BuildLabel kind="label">AutoGen_1151218d-a0b0-4ec1-a8a4-8ee7e54db6f7</BuildLabel>
  <BuildId kind="id">AutoGen_1151218d-a0b0-4ec1-a8a4-8ee7e54db6f7</BuildId>
  <BuildTimestamp kind="informative, summary">Tue, 06 Dec 2016 09:56:29 GMT</BuildTimestamp>
  <BuildMachine kind="informative">TFS15-BA-UH01</BuildMachine>
  <Configuration kind="informative">Release</Configuration>
  <Platform kind="informative">x64</Platform>      
</MSBuild>
```

how to get the correct build label, also ProjectVersionSpec element is not looking write, how to get the correct one.

```
<ProjectVersionSpec>C343847</ProjectVersionSpec>
```

Comment: Can you share your build definition settings?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We're experiencing the same problem.

Comment: no, i just moved on with that error.